# jQuery - How can I create a sub-menu indicator arrow image with my menu code (also using cufon)?

Tags: jquery, css, cufon

I want to add an arrow only beside menu links that contain sub-menus. I want the image to appear as a down arrow normally, then turn into an up arrow image when hovered over.

I managed to get a "+" symbol to display only on menus with sub-menus but I am not sure how to handle the hover change part or how to add an image instead of a text symbol.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/home.gif" width="75" height="50" alt="Home Page" /></a></li>
      <li><h6><a href="services.html">Top Menu</a></h6>to help you
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="link2.html">Link2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
//menu sub navigation
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#menu ul li h6").hover(function() { //When trigger is hovered...

    //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)

    $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

    $(this).parent().hover(function() {
    }, function(){  
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
    });


    //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
    }).hover(function() { 
        $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
    }, function(){  //On Hover Out
        $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
});

});
```

CSS:

```
#menu ul { height:50px; color:#FFF; }
#menu ul li { float:left; padding: 0 36px 0 0; position: relative;  }

#menu li ul.subnav { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 44px; background-     color:#505050;     
margin: 0; padding:0; display: none; float: left; width: 120px; z-index:100;  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:8px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright:8px; -webkit-border-  bottom-left-radius:8px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px; border-top:none; border-bottom:1px solid #444444; border-left:1px solid #444444; border-right:1px solid #444444; height:auto; }
#menu li ul.subnav li { margin: 0; padding: 0; clear: both; width: 120px; z-index:5; border-top:1px solid #444444; }
#menu li ul.subnav li a { margin: 0; padding: 0 10px; float: left; width: 120px; z-index:135; line-height:30px; text-align:left; }
#menu li.current li a { color:#3f3f3f; }

.width_280 { width:280px; }
.margin_0_20_0_0 { margin:0 20px 0 0; }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most tradition answer to this is to create little triangles in the different orientations that you want. Then, you can incorporate them in the menu items by making them background images, such as:

```
.menu_item {
  padding-left: 20px; /* make room for image */
  background: left middle url(triangle.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Then, as you are doing, apply classes when the menu is "opened", and using CSS to change the image. Maybe:

```
.subhover .menu_item {
  background: left middle url(other_triangle.png) no-repeat;
}
```

That's the basics... you can also do animations between states, sprite the images, build the triangles with CSS...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried originally but it misaligned my menu (which I could fix easily enough of course). Perhaps over thinking this. I was trying to use jQuery to add it automatically with ".find" instead of manually using css. How would I use ".find" to locate a submenu with my jQuery code and add a class for the arrow without messing up the "subhover" class?

Comment: At least as you start, it's simplest just to have jQuery add classes on hover, and do styling with CSS. I would probably try to keep the concepts (and naming) distinct: I'd add a "hovered" class and an "opened" class (for menu items with open submenus). You might also have a class for "has_submenu". That way you can get all your styles just the way you want them. After you get it working, you may be able to remove some of this granularity-- but if you blur all these distinct concepts together as you develop, it will be more confusing.